# Is there a way to insert div under some of navigation items in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the below HTML which I want to translate into wordpress function "`**wp_nav_menu()**`"

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li id="about-menu">
          <a href="#"> About Us </a>
          <div id="about-us"> 
              ..... 
              inner div(s) and 
              Paragraphs etc 
              ...... 
          </div>
       </li>
       <li id="contact-menu">
          <a href="#"> Contact Us </a>
          <div id="contact-us"> 
              ..... 
              inner div(s) and 
              Paragraphs etc 
              ...... 
          </div>
       </li>
       <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Any Idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom nav walker. There are no docs on wordpress.org, but you [could simply take a look at an existing walker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Comment: I am already using the same, but have no idea on how to extend it. Can you help please?